# Polymorphic Return Types in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polymorphism

Do polymorphic returns exist in MATLAB? I wish I could say what I'd to be returned if a function calls one of the methods of an object and then specify that for calculations it returns a value from a designated property. But I'm probably asking nonsense now. Please confirm that I'm dreaming. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually specify the return type in Matlab, you just return a value. The same function can easily return different types under different conditions. You can verify that there is no type information in function definitions by looking at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

For example, look at this function, which can return a string or matrix, based on the input argument:

```
function r = strange(arg)
   if arg == 1
       r = 'string';
   else
       r = [1, 2; 3 4];
   end
end
```

Now, that example may be handleable by static analysis, but consider this:

```
function r = evenstranger()
    if rand < 0.5
        r = 'string';
    else
        r = [1, 2; 3, 4];
    end
end
```

No way to know beforehand how that will turn out.

Comment: Thanks. That documentation link doesn't really demonstrate 'return different types under different conditions' though. What does 'different conditions' mean?

Comment: @ZakiMohzani I've added an example of a function returning different types based on an argument or on some other argument.

Comment: Yea, as I thought it would be. Thanks for the clarification.